# Capistrano 3 does not update files and code in the files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I am new to  Capistrano and need some help with setting it up. After I running command `cap deploy` it runs successfully with no errors, but it does not update anything on remote server only creates additional folders inside my_app directory with some files and also creates folder called `current` and placing all updates from github inside this folder.   Here is my `deploy.rb` file

```
lock '3.3.3'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:me/my_app.git'
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, "me"
set :stages, ["production"]
set :use_sudo, false

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'


namespace :deploy do
    after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup', "deploy:update_code"

    after :restart, :clear_cache do
        on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
            # Here we can do anything such as:
            # within release_path do
            #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
            # end
        end
    end

end
```

What is wrong! How can I make Capistrano to update files and content of the files in my_app folder on the remote server? Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: Since you are new to Capistrano, you may not know that this is how it does its job. Assuming your app reside in `/var/www/my_app`, there are a few directories and any of them does not contain your project source. First of them is `current` which is a symlink to `releases/SOME_TIMESTAMP`. Next is a `repo` directory which contain your bare repo, `releases` with a couple of last succeeded or failed deployments. The last one is `shared` and is having files or directories that have to be shared among releases (e.g. `config/database.yml`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you help me please! What should I do to make my server to use new code downloaded by Cpristrano. Or how can I synchronise code on github master branch with code on remote server? Thank you!

Comment: Your `deploy.rb` looks fine. Does deployment ends successfully? If so, `current` dir still does not contain new commits?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replay! Deployments ends successfuly and current dir does contains all updates and new commits. But what is next step, my server still running on old code. How to merge or replace old code with code from current folder? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Just cannot get this Capistrano. I thought this software synchronising files and content of the files between Github and remote server but it just coping all files in to the current folder on remote server. So it easier jus to run git pull on remote server and it will update all files? Just cannot to make this Capistrano  work as I need.

Comment: Capistrano lets you control your deployment process and in case of any failure, previous instance of deployment is still on the flow. Actually it does many other things, but need to me configured slightly. Ensure your app server restarts after deployment.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. Yes I can see that it got many configurations and settings. But simply - Which configuration or command can update all files and folders on remote server in my_app/ directory???

Comment: I suppose your files are up to date, but server is not kicked to restart, does it? The restart task depends on your server container. For unicorn e.g: `task :restart do; invoke 'unicorn:restart'; end`

Comment: Files up to date only inside the current folder `my_app/current` and files inside `my_app/` folder are old. So `current` folder contains new update copy of `my_app` folder. Servers what I am using is Apache and Passenger. And after manual restart it still running on old code from folder `my_app`

Comment: Or do I need to configure my server to run from `my_app/current` folder directory?

Comment: Read my first comment until you will understand it or google for capistrano tutorial to get the underlying idea of how it works.

Comment: Hi! I think I got it, I need to point server to work from the current folder. Thank you very much for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this problem was simple. When you use Capistrano, you have to point your server to use folder "current". For example I use apache passenger server with rails app, so in my config file I have to specify path `DocumentRoot /var/www/my_app/current/public`